# Error generating proxy with svcutil

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe, webservices-client

while trying to generate a proxy from this WebService (http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl) I'm receiving this error from svcutil:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl
>
> If this is a Windows (R) Communication
>   Foundation service to which you have
>   access, please check that you have
>   enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.  For help enabling
>   metadata publishing, please refer to
>   the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.
>
> WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>       URI: http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl
>
> ```
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
> ```
>
> 'http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl'.
>
> ```
> The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message
> ```
>
> does not match the content type of the
>   binding (application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8). If using a custom
>   encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is
>   implemented properly. The first 553
>   bytes of the response were: '
>      
>   ns1:Client.NoSOAPAction
>   no SOAPAction
>   header!    
>       usalwsc01
>       
>    '.
>
> ```
> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
> ```
>
> HTTP GET Error
>       URI: http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl
>
> ```
> The document at the url http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl
> ```
>
> was not recognized as a known document
>   type. The error message from each
>   known type may help you fix the
>   problem:
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema
>   should be  and its namespace
>   should be
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL
>   http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl
>   could not be found.'.
>     - The document format is not recognized.
>   - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document
>   (242, 18).'.
>
> - Namespace prefix 'impl:wb' is not defined.

I invoked svcutil with these parameters:

> svcutil /n:
>   *,WB.Client /et:WB.Client.WSResultObject
>   /o:Client\WBServices /noConfig
>   http://scdemo14.infor.com:9014/axis/services/wb:wsclocks-inbound?wsdl

Does anyone have an idea what can I do to generate a proxy? I cannot change the service on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the service uses a naming convention for the binding which is incompatible with svcutil. You can get round this as follows:

- Browse the service's WSDL URL and
  save the WSDL to a local file.
- Then make the following changes to the file:
- Remove the namespace prefix from the name used for the wsdl:binding i.e. change

  `name="wb:wsclocks-inboundSoapBinding"` to be

  **name="wsclocks-inboundSoapBinding"**
- Change the binding attribute of the wsdl:port attribute to match, and also remove the namespace prefix from the value of the name attribute, so it is just **wsclocks-inbound**.

Then run `svcutil <wsdl-file-path> /o:Client\WBServices /noConfig`